# What was the significance of the seven wonders of the ancient world in ancient life?

Tags: ancient-history

What is the background of the 7 wonders of the ancient world?

How significant were the wonders to those in ancient societies?

Comment: See [Seven Wonders of the Ancient World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Wonders_of_the_Ancient_World) : probably a mix of "ancient tourism" and the search for mythological roots of Greek civilization.

Comment: That's something you can easily google.